# How to convert group of numbers in text file into matrix array

Tags: arrays, matrix

[Groups of number in txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FckW7.png)

I have a group of numbers from simulation results in txt format,
but I have problem figuring out how to convert this data to visual studio in matrix rows and columns.

```
Eg. (txt file): 1 2 3 4
                2 3 4 5
                4 4 5 6
(Visual studio): Array[0][0]= 1
                 Array[1][0]= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure how visual studio works, however you might get some idea from the PHP code:

```
$txt = file_get_contents($filename);
$lines = explode("\n", $txt);
foreach ($lines as $l => $line) {
    $array[$l] = explode(' ', $line);
}
return $array;
```